# strpos код не срабатывает PHP

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Есть такой код для фильтрации URL. Но при каждом вводе данных срабатывает последный вариант.Подскажите ошибку. Заранне спасибо.

```
trait CheckEngine
{
    public function checkUrl($data)
    {
        $string = array(
            "home" , "about" , "freetemplate" , "contact" , "?" ,
            "auto" , "beauty" , "cleaning" , "education" , "auto",
            "cat", "=" , "$");

        foreach ($string as $key) 
        {
            if ($data = strpos($key, $data)) 
            {
                if ($data === false) 
                {
                    unset($data);
                }
                 else 
                {
                    return $data;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}



class TemplateController
{   
    use CheckEngine;
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        require_once("view/free-template.php");
        return true;
    }

    public function actionCategory()
    { 

        if (isset($_GET["cat"])) 
        {


            $cat = $this->checkUrl($_GET["cat"]);


            switch ($cat) 
            {
                case 'auto':
                print("auto");
                break;
                case 'beauty':
                print("beauty");
                break;  
                case 'cleaning':
                print("cleaning");
                break;
                case 'education':
                print("education");
                break;
                case 'other':
                print("other");
                break;      
                default:
                print("something");
                break;
            }

        }   

        require_once("view/free-template.php");
        return true;
    }

}

$template = new TemplateController();
$template->actionIndex();
$template->actionCategory();
```

Срабатывает только

```
                    default:
                    print("something");
                    break;
```

Comment: mvc - это, как бы, паттерн. Одно из его назначений - делать ооп код поддерживаемым (читай - легким для восприятия). От вашего кода извилины в мозгу завязываются узлами - это верный признак того, что что-то пошло не так.
Что-то мне подсказывает, что виновато переопределение `$data` внутри цикла внутри блока условий `if`

Comment: @rjhdby поддерживаю, но автор просто перепутал местами аргументы `strpos($data, $key)`  ну и `data` конечно же будет всегда 0 по ходу дела

Comment: Спасибо за ответ как можно исправить чтобы работало

Answer (score 2):

В документации по функции [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php) сказано:

> обратите внимание на то, что позиция строки отсчитывается от 0, а не от 1

Исходя из этого можно сделать вывод, что в блок `if ($data = strpos($key, $data))` метод никогда не входит, даже если соответствие было найдено `strpos` возвращает `0`, который в операторе `if` приводится к `false`.

Вследствие этого `checkUrl` ничего не возвращает и `$cat = $this->checkUrl($_GET["cat"]);` равно `null`.
Поэтому `switch` и попадает в блок `default`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function checkUrl($data)
    {

        $data = trim($data);
        $data = strip_tags($data);
        $data = stripcslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $stri = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"+","-","(",")","[","]","|","^",";",".","@");
        $repl = array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");
        $data = str_replace($stri, $repl, $data);
        return $data;
    }
```

`strpos` поменял на `str_replace` думаю что не взломают